# Issue with mongoid skip and geocoder near

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, mongoid, rails-geocoder

I have been working in a project for months now. Written in `3.2.x`, it uses `mongoid` as the ORM. Initially the database was hosted in mongolabs but recently we migrated it back to our application stack.The mongodb version we use now is 2.6.1. The code has been deployed in EC2. Everything was working properly but all of sudden, we were not getting proper results. When looking in to the issue, I found out that whenever we make an api call `with page > 1` the application is responding with any results. I am using `Kaminari` gem for pagination

I dumped the db locally and tested in my machine but everything is working fine. If I remove the pagination (limit and per in Kaminari), the api call fetches all the expected results, hence I didnt find any issue with other where clauses. I tried replacing Kaminari with Will_Paginate and the issue remains the same. If I look at the mongoid criteria, the pagination clause adds simple skip and limit clauses to the criteria. I have no idea where the issue lies or what am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

After more debugging the issue seems to be with the geocoder near function.

```
Item.near(coordinates,(params[:radius]||999999)).count #returns 43
Item.near(coordinates,(params[:radius]||999999)).page(1).per(10).count #returns 10
Item.near(coordinates,(params[:radius]||999999)).page(2).per(10).count #returns 0
```

Once again everything is working fine locally.

Comment: Is there a missing *not* in "the application is responding with any results"? Have you tried your queries in the MongoDB shell to see if the error is in MongoDB or the Ruby-land?

Comment: @muistooshort I tried direct queries from rails console and it was working as expected.

Comment: So what's different between what you're doing in the console and what your app is doing? Was your console hooked up to the same database as your app?

Comment: @muistooshort, YES, there are in the same environment. Thats what is pestering me a lot.

Comment: What is `params[:radius]`? Could it be a simple type problem? A string passed where someone is expecting a number?

Comment: @muistooshort No it isn't. I made sure it is just a number but most of time its just nil.